# How to avoid modal to reload controller again?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

When initialize my controller and page, I'll send some data to third party server. I have a button which triggers a modal. When user clicks the button, my controller is initialized again so the data is sent again. How to avoid it?

View:

```
View:

<button id="sendEmailButton" type='button'ng-click="sendEmail()"</button> 

Controller:

$scope.sendEmail = function() {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'sendEmail.html'
    });
}
```

```

Answer (score 3):

Sample modals from ui-bootstrap documentation.  As you can see modals get their own controller separate from the main view.  This should solve your issue.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleAnimation()">Toggle Animation ({{ animationsEnabled }})</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

});

// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

its seems like your using the same controller for